# How to use Hydra Config alongside user-defined parameters?

Tags: python, configuration, yaml, fb-hydra

Is there a way to use `Hydra Config` alongside other parameters?

I want some arguments to be defined in the code, and others to be read from the config file.

```py
@hydra.main(config_path="conf", config_name="vehicle_manager")
def __init__(self, client: carla.Client, cfg: DictConfig) -> None :
  self.client = client
  self.traffic_manager = self.client.get_trafficmanager(cfg.tm_port)
```

The `client` will be provided by another module, and `cfg` should be read from the config file.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I am still looking for an answer for it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current implementation of `@hydra.main` requires the decorated function to take just one parameter, which is the `DictConfig` (or `ListConfig`) object resulting from config composition.

One possibility is to use the [compose API](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.2/advanced/compose_api/) which gives more flexibility to use a functional programming paradigm.

Another possibility is to refactor your application so that the `@hydra.main`-decorated function takes just one parameter (i.e. `cfg: DictConfig`) and then have that decorated function create the `carla.Client` instance.

A final possibility would be to use Hydra's [instantiate API](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/advanced/instantiate_objects/overview/) so that the `carla.Client` instance can be specified as a *part* of the `cfg` object.

```py
@hydra.main(config_path="conf", config_name="vehicle_manager")
def app(self, cfg: DictConfig) -> None :
  assert cfg.carla_client._target_ == "carla.Client"
  client = hydra.utils.instantiate(cfg.carla_client)
  assert isinstance(client, carla.Client)
  self.client = client
  ...
```